# angular2 - cannot import 3rd party module

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I am trying to load 3rd party module, as in the documentation, generally, something like this:

```
import { ResponsiveModule } from 'ng2-responsive';
```

I don't have any error during import. 
but when I run locally, I get the following error:
`http://localhost:3001/ng2-responsive 404 (Not Found)` 
I tried using relative paths and include the library in `systemjs.config.js` but get the same errors..

Comment: Did you install `ng2-responsive` through npm? I'd suggest using `angular-cli` instead of SystemJS because it looks like issue with systemjs configuration.

Comment: what are the steps you  used to use the **ng2-responsive**

Comment: have you done  npm i ng2-responsive --save ?? did you find that package included in package.json ?? Have you included it in angular-cli.json "apps" scripts ??

Comment: I used this command : `  npm i ng2-responsive --save` I am developing in Webstorm.

Comment: in package.json I see his:     "ng2-responsive": "^0.7.2",

Comment: This is the instructions: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-responsive

Answer (score 0):

Try using
`var ResponsiveModule = require('ng2-responsive')`
instead of
`import { ResponsiveModule } from 'ng2-responsive';`

Comment: what is the difference?